# How to override pytest.ini when running tests from the command line?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a codebase containing multiple python packages. There is also a pytest.ini file that contains the names of these files.

example directory structure:

```
main_dir
  |
  |
  |--- package1
  |
  |--- package2
  |
  |--- pytest.ini
```

pytest.ini looks like this

```
[pytest.ini]
addopts = package1 package2
```

The issue is because of `pytest.ini` I am not able to run tests just package wise. For example `py.test package1\` now runs tests for `package2` tests as well.

If I remove pytest.ini file, the command works as expected. Only option I see is to maintain an uncommitted version of pytest.ini which I keep changing according to my needs.

How do I override the pytest.ini settings and run tests only package wise?

Comment: Why do you need that entry in your .ini anyway? Can't you just remove `addopts = package1 package2` and run tests by specifying the path i.e. `py.test package1`?

Comment: The ini is for automatic test discovery for our jenkins

Comment: Ok, but why do you need that specific entry in the ini?

Comment: There are other directories too. Which have tests in legacy code that won't work. So we want exclude those tests.

Comment: I suggest then to mark them using `pytest.mark.legacy` and run tests with `py.test -m 'not legacy'`

Comment: Alternatively, in `pytest.ini`, `norecursedirs = unwantedpackage1 package1/unwantedmodule1` also works. But it requires that these paths be unique.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `-o/--override-ini`. From pytest help text:

```
 -o OVERRIDE_INI, --override-ini=OVERRIDE_INI
                    override ini option with "option=value" style, e.g. `-o
                    xfail_strict=True -o cache_dir=cache`.
```

But your situation will require another workaround since your addopts options are not in the form `option=value` since it is a positional argument.

```
#pytest.ini file
[pytest]
   addopts = 
    -k="package1 or package2"
```

And, while running tests, you can use `pytest -o k=package1`. `-k` is used to select tests based on expression.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Adding an `[addopts]` section like that is undocumented, and AFAICT is not used by pytest. It's essentially creating a separate section from the `[pytest]` ini config section. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: You are right, @machow . Updated the pytest.ini file.

Answer (score 3):

```
pytest -c MyTestGetJson.ini
pytest -c MyTestGetXML.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

addopts is meant for mostly configuration options, since it always adds the given options entirely

if all test folders are always added, then of course it always find all tests

Comment: You are right. Now I am using `norecursedirs` to exclude legacy tests that need not be run.